# Code littered with asserts

Tags: c++, c

Hi I am programming on some device.
There is some sample with such code:

```
Verify(SomeFunc(argc, argv) == SDK_OK);

Verify(SomeOtherFunction(&st_initialData) == SDK_OK);

Verify(SomeOtherFunction2(x,y) == SDK_OK);
```

In doc, Verify is defined as 'similar' to assert.

My question is: if I build my project in `Release` mode, what will happen with above statements? Will they lose their power? Will the `Verify` have any effect still?

To avoid possible problem with above, will I have to replace above codes with checking return values like this?:

```
if(SomeFunc(argc, argv) == SDK_OK)
{
// we are fine
}
else
{
// handle error somehow, such that it is also available in Release mode
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: "Similar" doesn't mean "identical"

Comment: As the `Verify` function/macro is private to your project, there's no way we can answer that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `Assert` is defined that it only works in Debug mode (so seems it works like ordinary assert). And then like I said `Verify` is defined as same to assert in Debug mode, it doesn't say much about Release mode; doc isn't very clear.

Comment: @dmcr_code So you expect us to explain to you how something works which is unique to your organization and isn't even properly documented?

Comment: @Philipp: I expect you nothing. Anyway, assume it works as plain assert, then in Release mode, above lines will not check any return codes right?

Comment: @dmcr_code as long as you don't show us the implementation of `Verify`, your guess is as good as ours.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to say, as it seems that it is your project which implements `Verify`, as a macro or as a function. Why don't you take a look at the implementation?

That being said, MFC framework has `VERIFY` macro which is similar to `ASSERT`, with the distinction that the expression is always evaluated, even in release build, but doesn't do anything if result of the expression is false. This might be the similar approach, as your examples seem to call some functions which can affect the system state.

Comment: If the MFC verify version does NOTHING when the function fails, then what's the benefit in using that? Then I think it would be better to check for return codes from functions manually and fail somehow like I mentioned in my question right? (I will try to find more info on this Verify in my project)

Comment: @dmcr_code The reason for assertions (or something in its spirit) is that code fails hard during testing on the slightest inconsistency while it tries to keep running in production. The mindset behind this is that a silent bug is considered better than a crash in the production environment. Whether or not this is a good approach is material for a lengthy discussion. In the end it depends on how critical it is that the application works accurate and how bad it is when it crashes. These priorities need to be weighted against each other for every project.

Comment: @dmcr_code It's useful when you need to call a function whose failure should not happen - you need the function to always execute, *and* you want to assert it doesn't fail.

Comment: I see `verify` in MFC is like it always executes the method inside it but does not check for return codes. Assert in release **might** not execute what's inside right? How do people check for errors in Release builds then?

Comment: @dmcr_code With the verify-pattern it is possible that the release-build logs any failed verifications so they can be analyzed later. Please don't ask if your implementation of `Verify` does that, because nobody outside of your organization can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the MFC VERIFY macro or something very similar.
Using this macro is safe for release builds. The argument is executed in any case, just the macro itself does nothing in release.
In contrast to this, the ASSERT macro is completely skipped in release builds, so the "side effects" of the argument do not happen. Therefore, VERIFY is used if the argument is required for the actual program flow, and ASSERT is used when the argument is for asserting only.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly you will not have to replace them. If your project wanted just to remove the calls in production compilation, it would probably have just plain `assert` directly. Try to read the source of the project (always a good idea) and understand what he macro does.